# Date picker in ng-grid is not working with IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, ng-grid

```js
        $scope.idCardValidityTracker = {
            data: 'data',                          //Test data
            enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
            enableRowSelection: false,
            columnDefs: [{ field: 'idCardNumber', displayName: 'ID Card Number', visible: true },
                        { field: 'validFromDate', displayName: 'Valid From', enableCellEditOnFocus: true, enableCellSelection: true, editableCellTemplate: '</b><input type="date" value="MM-dd-yyyy"  ng-class="' + 'colt' + '+ $index"  ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD"/>', cellFilter: 'date:\'MM-dd-yyyy\'' },
                        { field: 'validToDate', displayName: 'Valid To', enableCellEditOnFocus: true, enableCellSelection: true, editableCellTemplate: '</b><input type="date" value="MM-dd-yyyy" ng-class="' + 'colt' + '+ $index"  ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />', cellFilter: 'date:\'MM-dd-yyyy\'' }]
        };
```

```css
<style>
 .gridStyle {
        max-height: 170px;
        resize: horizontal;
        border: 1.5px ridge #fdfef9;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 2px;
        resize: both;
    }

</style>
```

```html
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="idCardValidityTracker" style="text-align:center; align-items:center;"></div>
```

Date pickers in ng-grid are working fine with Google chrome, but not in Internet Explorer 10. Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you make a plunker?

Comment: in chrome i am getting date picker popup after clicking on date editable cell. In the case of internet explorer the cells are editable, but not getting any popup after clicking on date editable cells.

Answer (score 0):

**Date picker not working in IE**

Internet explorer doesn't support date field.that's why not working your code

```
 <input type="date"> // IE doesn't support
```

alternatively you can use bootstrap date picker it will working IE too.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker